# Cloned Partition and can't boot from it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

a year ago I installed Ubuntu on a small partition of 16GB because I thought I'd not use it that much, well that is not the case and I currently find myself needing a lot more space.

So because I did not want to install Ubuntu all over again and loose my data I decided to create a new partition of 80GB and paste my current partition into it, I did it with Gparted.

However when I turn on my computer, the option to boot from the new partition doesn't show up, rather only my current Ubuntu partition shows up, which is too small to keep working with.

How can I boot from the new partition I made?

Edit: The reason I did not simply resize the working Partition to make it bigger is because the GParted tool only allowed me to shrink partitions

Comment: Why not resize the working partition? Is the cloned partition in a different drive? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1278366/edit) and add all the new information in the question.

Comment: Did you update grub entries?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? If you clone a partition you have duplicate UUIDs which are not allowed. Often easier to do new install & restore your data & settings from your normal backup. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair